# Discount card reduction calculator

Tags: java, object-oriented, console

I have started programming a couple of months ago and have recently applied for an internship. One of the assignments was to create a console application, the assignment can be seen here - > [HERE](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1h6x_SzF4wmIBJwleoa1ND9CQzGbARiz5)

My implementation is this:

I have created an abstract class called DiscountCard which holds all the info, getters and setters, and has one abstract method of calculateDiscountRate.

```
public abstract class DiscountCard {

    private String owner;
    private int turnover;
    private int purchaseValue;
    private double discountRate;


    public DiscountCard(int turnOver, int purchaseValue){

        setTurnover(turnOver);
        setPurchaseValue(purchaseValue);

    }

    abstract void calculateDiscountRate();

    public String getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }

    public void setOwner(String owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
    }

    public int getTurnover() {
        return turnover;
    }

    public void setTurnover(int turnOver) {

        if(turnOver>=0) {
            this.turnover = turnOver;
        }else{
            System.out.println("Turnover can't be less than 0.");
        }

    }

    public int getPurchaseValue() {
        return purchaseValue;
    }

    public void setPurchaseValue(int purchaseValue) {

        if(purchaseValue>=0) {
            this.purchaseValue = purchaseValue;
        }else{
            System.out.println("Purchase value can't be less than 0.");
        }
    }

    public void setDiscountRate(double discountRate) {
        this.discountRate = discountRate;
    }

    public double getDiscountRate() {
        return discountRate;
    }
}
```

Then, there are 3 Card classes (Bronze,Silver,Gold) which implement the above class and override its abstract method:

```
 package com.test.DiscountCards;

    public class GoldDiscountCard extends DiscountCard {


        public GoldDiscountCard(int turnOver, int purchaseValue){

            super(turnOver,purchaseValue);
            calculateDiscountRate();
        }

        @Override
        void calculateDiscountRate() {

            setDiscountRate(2);

            setDiscountRate(getTurnover()/100 + getDiscountRate());

            if(getDiscountRate()>10){
                setDiscountRate(10);
            }


        }


    }
```

Next is the StoreCalculator Class which takes an instance of DiscountCard class and calculates the discount and total.

```
package com.test;

import com.practice.DiscountCards.DiscountCard;

public class StoreCalculator {

    private DiscountCard discountCard;

    public StoreCalculator(DiscountCard discountCard){
        this.discountCard = discountCard;
    }

    public double calculateDiscount(){
        return discountCard.getPurchaseValue() * discountCard.getDiscountRate()/100;
    }

    public double calculateTotal(){
        return discountCard.getPurchaseValue() - calculateDiscount();
    }
}
```

And at last i have a class that takes the info from DiscountCard class and Calculator class and prints it to a console.

```
import com.test.DiscountCards.DiscountCard;

public class PayDesk {

    public static void print(DiscountCard discountCard){

        StoreCalculator calculator = new StoreCalculator(discountCard);

        System.out.println("Purchase value: $"+ discountCard.getPurchaseValue() );
        System.out.println("Discount rate: "+ discountCard.getDiscountRate()+"%" );
        System.out.println("Discount: $"+ calculator.calculateDiscount() );
        System.out.println("Total: $"+ calculator.calculateTotal());


    }
}
```

My question is if this code implements OOP and is there something i should improve. I have send this code for a review to a company, i just want to know if there can be an improvement so i can learn more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The OO part seems to be OK when it comes to the type inheritance and the choice of an abstract class.

## Code review.

### For the abstract class

```
public DiscountCard(int turnOver, int purchaseValue){
```

This is a public constructor for a class that cannot be instantiated, consider `protected` instead. It also contains a `turnOver`, but that's specific to an owner it seems to me. So that doesn't make sense without the `owner` string. Similarly, I don't think the card is *specific to one particular purchase*. The card is applied on a particular purchase.

```
    setTurnover(turnOver);
    setPurchaseValue(purchaseValue);
```

Generally you'd set the fields directly, instead of calling the public methods. Calling methods can be dangerous, especially if they can be overridden.

```
abstract void calculateDiscountRate();
```

For what? That depends on `purchaseValue` but that should not depend on any class fields, as already established.

```
public String getOwner() {
    return owner;
}
```

Here you make a classic mistake: never leave your objects in an invalid state. As the owner may not be set, this method could return `null`.

```
public void setOwner(String owner) {
    this.owner = owner;
}
```

No. If the **holder** of the card can change then this would be in the model, and I don't see that. Generally cards are **personalized** and are therefore not transferable (at least from the payment desk's point of view).

```
public void setTurnover(int turnOver) {
    if(turnOver>=0) {
        this.turnover = turnOver;
    }else{
        System.out.println("Turnover can't be less than 0.");
    }
}
```

The turnover may actually be negative if the customer decided to return. In this kind of situations it is important to perform a reality check: what could happen. Furthermore, I guess that this should be called after each period of time (it's for the "previous month" according to the instructions. So call it, say, `setTurnoverOfLastMonth()` or something similar.

```
public void setDiscountRate(double discountRate) {
    this.discountRate = discountRate;
}
```

Is that really a public call, you override the discount rate? Seems to me that you'd have to switch cards for that.

### For the gold card:

```
calculateDiscountRate();
```

By now you should have noticed that there are more rates possible, you are still trying to get along with one.

```
setDiscountRate(2);

setDiscountRate(getTurnover()/100 + getDiscountRate());
```

And you aren't just overwriting the single discount rate in the second call?

```
if(getDiscountRate()>10){
    setDiscountRate(10);
}
```

Leukoplast patching ain't gonna help, son.

### For the store calculator

Where are the purchases? In the card?

I'd expect something like:

```
public Payment calculateResult(double purchaseValue);
```

Where the `Payment` contains all the details (card used, discount percentage, discount value and of course the final price).

Note too that the examples have a purchase value with `.00` behind it. Somehow that indicates to me that every cent is appreciated (and you store as an `int` - which is actually fine **if it means cents**).

### For the PayDesk

Just prints out stuff. Maybe correct, maybe it isn't, but just printing the bill is not what I was expecting. Probably can be merged with the `StoreCalculator` although I like the fact that you've created a separate calculator. That would certainly be a good idea for a more complicated `PayDesk` class.

---

Beware: it says in your requirements: "create instances with sample data as shown in Example outputs section;"

Now I don't personally think that the purchase should ever be part of the card data, but if it is stated this way I'd almost include it myself as a field.

---

Very non-nerdy of me, but I'd include a welcoming message for the card holder (Thank you for your purchase, ). Your GOLD CARD discount is: ... Etc... This would show your employer that you can act outside what is basic development.

And probably I'd also welcome non-card holders to make a purchase.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your answer is very helpful. One thing i am not sure i quite understand, about setting the DiscountRate. Should i set it directly in a constructor of a child card class and get rid of the setter?

Comment: I don't think you should talk about *one* discount rate if you read the assignment carefully. Any information that is required to *calculate* the discount rate should be set when it becomes available. But it is known for the different cards even *before* they are constructed, right? This information could just be codified or placed - preferably - in a constant or two - three - four.